# Jobs-count in navigation

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, variables

I'm trying to add a number to my menu-item "Jobs" to show how many jobs are available.

Here's an [example](https://wijs.be)

I have the value (count of jobs), but I don't know how to add the number to my menu-item.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'dfib_contact_menu_atts', 10, 3 );
function dfib_contact_menu_atts( $atts, $item, $args ) {

    $jobs = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'jobs' ));

    if ($jobs->have_posts()) { 
        $count_posts = wp_count_posts( 'jobs' )->publish;
        echo "<span class='jobs__count'>$count_posts</span>"; 
    }

    // The ID of the target menu item
    $menu_target = "menu-item-19";

      // inspect $item
      if ($item->ID == $menu_target) {
        $atts["data-badge"] = $count_posts;
      }
      return $atts;
}
?>
```

I want to add this number to the menu-item with class "menu-item-job", but I don't know how to do this in php

Answer (score 0):

You should use nav_menu_link_attributes() hook as it's explained here:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121123/how-to-add-a-data-attribute-to-a-wordpress-menu-item

That is, something like:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'wpse121123_contact_menu_atts', 10, 3 );
function wpse121123_contact_menu_atts( $atts, $item, $args )
{
  // The ID of the target menu item
  $menu_target = 123;

  // inspect $item
  if ($item->ID == $menu_target) {
    $atts['data-badge'] = $count_posts;
  }
  return $atts;
}
```

So new attribute "data-badge" with value `$count_posts` will appear for you menu item (assuming it has id 123).

Then you have to implement the same front-end solution as on your example site to display this attribute as it's displayed there.

Comment: I'm not really trying to change the whole title, but just add an extra element. I added an example to my question.

Comment: I suppose I place this in my functions.php? Where do I use the code to get $count_posts (the piece I already found)?

Comment: Add it above the "$menu_target = 123;" part

Comment: Now it displays 12 times, but nog as data-badge. I updated my question with the full code I have right now

Comment: This code is for adding attribute "data-badge", but it's up to front-end implementation how it will be used. I suggested you to check how it's don on site you gave as example. Also, you have to adjust code to your needs - to set proper menu item id, menu id in function name and so on...